# Organise my mutual recursive types

Tags: f#, types, mutual-recursion

Is it possible to have mutual recursive types (`[<Struct>]`) spread across different files? The types are directly under a namespace.

My solution is to put them in one big file and use `type ... and ...  and ... etc` construction. Is it the only way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a technique called untying the recursive knot where you parameterize one over the other.

So this:

```
type a = B of b
and b = A of a
```

becomes:

```
type 'b a = B of 'b
type b = A of b a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this kind of technique often used? I feel that F# design guidelines recommand to put all in one big file, right?

Comment: I certainly use it often and recommend to our clients that they use it often but, yes, it does seem to be underappreciated.

Comment: `untying the recursive knot` is very useful when you try to memoize functions. It has been described in the *When we need substitution* of http://typeocaml.com/2015/01/20/mutable/